# java programming main showing error 341

Tags: java

I wrote a simple java code to make a password out of the inputs that the user gave nut it is giving me an error

```
import java.util.*;
public class PinPassqord {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 3 numbers : ");
        int n1,n2,n3;
        n1 = sc.nextInt();
        n2 = sc.nextInt();
        n3 = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr1 = new int[3];
        int[] arr2 = new int[3];
        int[] arr3 = new int[3];
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            arr1[i] = n1%10;
            arr2[i] = n2%10;
            arr3[i] = n3%10;
            n1/=10;
            n2/=10;
            n3/=10;
        }
        int max = 0;
        for(int i=2;i>=0;i--)
        {
            max = arr1[i];
            if(arr2[i] > max)
            {
                max = arr2[i];
            }
            else if(arr3[i] > max)
            {
                max = arr2[i];
            }
            else
            {
                max = arr1[i];
            }
            arr[i+1] = max;
        }
        for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
        {
            max = arr[i];
            if(arr[i] > max)
            {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
        arr[0] = max;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

}
```

I cant seem to know what error it is as it shows

```
error at main() code  341
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

at PinPassqord.main(PinPassqord.java:3)
```

the class I am working in is named PinPassword

can anyone help?

Comment: No, the class is named PinPassqord with q instead of w. I assume you are using eclipse?

Comment: yes eclipse photon

Comment: Yes the class is named PinPassqord

Comment: As mentioned by others, your `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));` is _outside of the `main` method_. This is an error for two reasons: (1) The statement is not inside a method and (2) the variable `arr` is not visible outside `main`. These errors are _compilation_ errors and would be reported as such if you weren't using the Eclipse compiler. The Eclipse compiler allows erroneous code to be compiled and will instead throw an `Error` at runtime when the problematic code gets executed. While this is useful (testing of code while other code doesn't compile) it can be confusing to beginners

Comment: And the real answer is: learn what a *compiler error* is. Meaning: that message tells you that you try to *run* a class that doesn't even compile. The eclipse IDE puts those red underlines under bad syntax, and it tells your class contains errors. There is *no* point in hitting the run button while you have compiler errors.

Answer (score 3):

The java file name is `PinPassword` but in your source code the class name is `PinPassqord` and the scope is `public`,they are not the same.If the class is `public`,then the names should keep the same

You need to rename your java file  from `PinPassqord` tp `PinPassword`

Also below code(the last line) is out of the `main` method,it should within it

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: The java class in package name and the program are  the same names but it's not the issue,  all programs br=efore this were running fine only this giving error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));` line is written outside the `main` method. Put the `}` from before to after `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));` to include it within the main method.